# Trouble when using Categorical Embedder package

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization, embedding

Here is my code:

```
import categorical_embedder as ce
```

and the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64b4bf2d5fa7> in <module>
----> 1 import categorical_embedder as ce
      2 
      3 # ce.get_embedding_info identifies the categorical variables, # of unique values and embedding size and returns a dictionary
      4 embedding_info = ce.get_embedding_info(X)
      5 embedding_info

c:\users\rs085237\desktop\data\myenv\lib\site-packages\categorical_embedder\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from keras.models import Sequential, Model, model_from_json
      3 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, Activation, Input, concatenate, Reshape, Flatten
----> 4 from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
      5 from keras.layers.advanced_activations import PReLU
      6 from keras.optimizers import Adam

ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization'
```

My python version is 3.6.8

Tensorflow is 2.5.0 and keras is 2.5.0

I think version of python, tensorflow and keras might have some conflicts.

In that case, how do i install new venv as in same directory (I want to upgrade python to 3.9 to see what happen).

Thank you

Comment: Could you try `from tf.keras.layers import BatchNormalization`?

Comment: I tried to reinstall tensorflow, and now it comes to Adam error, that must be a conflict between version of tensorflow and categorical embder.

Comment: For those who seek same problem as mine, this is mismatch of version of tensorflow, python and keras. I tried and found appropriate verion: python: 3.8.6, tensor: 2.5.0,keras: 2.4.3

Comment: Hi! @PhạmTâm ,You could also downgrade Keras to 2.4.3 to resolve the issue. Thanks! Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718482/11530462